# Unable to fetch Image from WhatsApp Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources, whatsapp

I am trying to fetch the image received by WhatsApp from its Notification

In `Resource`, the `Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE` & `Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON` always returns `null` or `0`

I do receive `Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON`, but it is the DP of the sender

On debugging and evaluating the `StatusBarNotification` object, I see a property called `mSmallIcon` that has value with type `Resource` and `pkg = com.whatsapp`

But I don't know what parameter to pass to fetch the value of that property (see image for reference)

Please help

Here's the evaluated version of `StatusbarNotification` [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nAbY.png)